# update id instead of select, delete and insert?

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

What I want to do is run a php script that chooses certain mysql entries and just move them to the top of the table(or just auto increment the id column just like when inserting).

Explanation: I have a table with 100 entries. Entry n. 49 and entry 88 have to be updated just like this: entry 49 is deleted, all the data is still in/inserted in the table, but has the id of 101.

the same for entry 88: row with id column of value 88 is deleted/updated, a new entry/same entry updated appears with id of 102, but same data.

Also, no problems like duplicate id should occur after script has ran, asking for a mysql-friendly solution.

Did you understand?

**My question is: how can this be done the most effective and simple way?**

The only option I have in mind is really long and seems unnecessarily complex: select the whole row, delete it, insert a new row with all the data and let the id auto increment itself...

Now if anyone would care to share with me their thoughts on this matter, I would be most grateful!

Other info: script will be run once a day, powerful apache dedicated server. No optimization needed, question asking for simple solution asks for an easy way to deal with my problems without actually needing to work so hard.

---

Thanks everyone for your help! I appreciate every last piece of your answers and comments! As I think this problem cannot be solved more simply than I stated above, using a piece of PHP, I am closing this question now. Again I say, thanks to everyone that answered! If you have a thought about a solution to the problem either than using php, please answer here and I will read it, or at least maybe we will help any other person who will be reading this thread in the future, assuming 2012 will not bring the end of the world... in that case, nobody will read this thread anymore and you may as well not post at all... but I like to think that the future is ours to decide :P... Thanks again everyone! Cheers!

Comment: Don't use the ID in that way.  Create another column and update that one with abandon and glee.

Comment: update id?? **Never ever** change the id!!!

Comment: @Marvo. Couldn't agree more. Ids are just for referencing and foreign keys and such. Don't modify them for sorting, and don't recycle them.

Comment: yeah... I guess you're right but still... any mysql command that could do like "update insert where bla bla bla something like this?"... google searches were in vain, btw... thanks anyway!

Comment: that just the auto increment is there a reason for wanting it reordered

Answer (score 2):

You know there's an [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) type query too right?

## WARNING! Pure evil ahead!

```
UPDATE `table`
SET `field1`='value1', `field2` = 'value2', `id`=LAST_INSERTED_ID()+1
WHERE `id` = 49;
```

Why the Pure Evil warning? You must NEVER *EVER* **EVER** ***EVER*** change the ID of an existing entry, as it is bound to mess up your table. The last code was pure theory and is not recommended for use.

[Manual Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

Comment: oh come on!... of course, I just said that! did you read my question to start with?

Comment: Of course I have. Your question isn't 100% clear though. Please elaborate and clarify your problem.

Comment: ok, so: I have a record which was inserted in the database with the id of 55 of 100. Now I want it to be the record 101, but not re-inserting it (no duplicate data), more like telling mysql that this record is the new one it has to insert, letting mysql auto increment the id field itself. Is this clearer? Thanks for your answer so far, anyway. :)

Comment: That is default behavior. Even if you added records 1-100, and deleted ID 55, the auto-increment count should be set to 101.

Comment: Rikudo Sennin yes but his problem is that he dont want to delete and insert - he want to use update (he just don't know that it is possible :) he said that he needs the most clear and simple way to achieve it = update, but not like u wrote - he want column to get actual autoincrement id)

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh that explains it! Will update my answer soon to include that. Thanks @gron

Comment: No! by updating this, you change the ID manually and mysql has no idea of this, thus will not take notice of the incrementation and this will result in duplicate id and lots of problems! any other idea?

Answer (score 1):

I came across an article explaining [A Point In Time database design](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/database-design-a-point-in-time-architecture/). The article describes using [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) to implement the design. You might use this solution to create a trigger which, instead of deleting, updates the id.

As stated before, it is really dangerous to mess with your ID-s and will most certainly corrupt your data sooner or later.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know why do you need it, but this would be the best query I think:

`UPDATE %table% SET id = (SELECT Auto_increment FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = DATABASE() && table_name = '%table%') WHERE id = %id%`

If you want to be sure that the DB won't get messed up, use transaction (InnoDB) or LOCK (MyISAM)

InnoDB

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE %table% SET id = (SELECT Auto_increment FROM information_schema.tables
```

WHERE table_schema = DATABASE() && table_name = '%table%') WHERE id = %id%;
    COMMIT;

MyISAM

```
LOCK TABLES %table% WRITE;
UPDATE %table% SET id = (SELECT Auto_increment FROM information_schema.tables
```

WHERE table_schema = DATABASE() && table_name = '%table%') WHERE id = %id%;
    UNLOCK TABLES;

Comment: the last snippet you posted, does it act just like inserting a new row, meaning that mysql's internal 'incrementor' will know that the last id used is 101 and not 100, like before? Also, could you please state to me briefly what happens when the table is locked? can it not be written to or read from? Thanks for your answer and thanks in advance for your next comment explaining me all this. Cheers!

Comment: Hello, this is complete solution. It is really simple - transaction/lock prevent's OTHER threads to update the table while your transaction/lock queries are being executed. That means there is no possibility of table corruption - because noone can write to table while you do. Yes, it is that simple. And now how it works - simple update statement `UPDATE ***** SET id = xx WHERE id = yy`, where xx is select query which gets actual (the next) autoincrement value for table ***** from the mysql internal table (somethink like this query is done with each insert - internally)

Comment: will the users be able to read the data in the table during the lock time? (this is purely curiosity as the query would take waaaay less than needed to bother anyone). and also, by using the query, mysql does take notice of the new value of the autoincremented id, right? Thanks a lot for your answer, I hope this solves it pretty good! Cheers man!

Comment: yes, users would be able to read from table - it just prevents other users to update the table :)